# Sending acr_values when using GetOauthSignInLinkAsync

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am implementing a teams bot and are using Identity Server as authentication that we set up in the Bot Channel. It works fine when using

`var signInLink = await (turnContext.Adapter as IUserTokenProvider).GetOauthSignInLinkAsync(turnContext, _connectionName, cancellationToken);`

However, it seems like we can't add the preferred login method to the call by adding, for example, &acr_values=idp:Aad
I can't find a way to add extra parameters when creating the link, I would expect it to be possible to send to GetOauthSignInLinkAsync when creating the link, however it doesn't seem to be possible.

It does not work when adding it to the link once it is created, ie https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=xxx&acr_values=idp:Aad
Does anyone know if it's possible to do this? or have an idea of a workaround?
Regards Martin

Comment: GetOauthSignInLinkAsync returns a string of the url.  Have you tried just concatenating your acr_values to it?

Comment: Yes,  I have tried to add it to the created URL, but it is removed when redirected to the IdentityServer.
https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=xxx&acr_values=idp:Aad

Comment: @Martin, Is this issue pending?

Comment: This is still pending, we have reached out to Microsoft to see if there is any solution

Answer (score 2):

Right now there is not a way to add extra parameters to the sign in link. However, if you configure one of the generic oauth providers, you can customize the URL that is sent to the identity provider. You can follow an example that Eric added to this issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/140